# Using voltage stabilizer AND UPS for pc?

Tags: electrical

So I'm in a bit of an odd position now. I have both an Uninterruptible Power Supply with 3 outputs ([this one](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B009CVTVH6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) as well as a voltage stabilizer for my TV with 2 outputs lying around. Now, my UPS has some voltage stabilization, but the voltage stabilizer's probably better at the task.

I need to connect 3 devices, all of which should have UPS power when then there's no power and to be protected by the best voltage stabilisation, so my setup will be:

Wall Socket -> Voltage Stabiliser -> UPS -> TV, PC, wifi router

Is there anything wrong with this setup? Will having the voltage be stabilized twice have any possibility of a negative effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "but the voltage stabilizer's *probably* better at the task". What makes you think so?   "Is there anything wrong with this setup?". We couldn't possibly tell you without the specifics of the 'voltage stabilizer'.-- for example it may be designed for a very small load.

Comment: this is really off topic here "The core of this site is around parts of your home that are typically included when you buy or sell it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances."   Try electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: A stabilizer is a waste of power with a ups in my opinion. UPS is all the stabilization needed on higher end units you can set the range when the ups shifts to battery power on very delicate equipment I have worked on we set the ups to run off the batteries 100% and the charger would keep the batteries charged, if there was any disruption in the service the load never saw it until the batteries were depleted I think running a stabilizer with a ups would require the same power consumption as 100% UPS with a fast crossover time but add more to go wrong.

Comment: Super User would be the appropriate site to migrate this to.

Comment: You don't want or need a stabilizer before the UPS.  The UPS provides voltage regulation and relies on the AC waveform from the wall.  Feeding the UPS from a voltage stabilizer could potentially interfere with proper operation of the UPS.

Comment: Some do, some don't.  A lot of UPSs just connect mains power straight through and throw a relay to changeover.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `voltage stabilizer`?

Comment: since those are all DC devices, you probably don't need any conditioning unless your service is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, as was rightly pointed out in the comments, as it's pretty much a single d.c source in the end. This question's probably more suited to electronics too. And the voltage stabiliser I'm using can bear the load of all 3. And while connecting the UPS directly would work just as fine, it makes practically no difference, and considering the frequent power cuts and voltage changes in my area, while it is overkill, it certainly protects my setup.